# Using CVX in MATLAB and Python support

Tags: python, matlab, convex-optimization

I was tweaking with CVX Toolbar in MATLAB. I have installed Python3.6 as I realized this is needed by the conelp function. Going into the details, I have realized that the command ``pyversion" on my MATLAB return an empty array instead of the required data.

While running a simple example (available on CVX Documentation, and attached below), I keep getting error

Undefined variable "py" or class "py.dict".

Error in conelp (line 57)
py_opt = py.dict();.

It seems that conelp function in CVX requires Python support, which is installed in my computer, but not accessible by MATLAB. The MWE of the code is produced below

```
c = [-4 -5]';
 G = [2 1; 1 2; -1 0; 0 -1];
 h = [3. 3. 0. 0.]';
 sol = conelp(c,G,h);
```

I am supposed to get the solution due to the constraints c, G and h, but I get the error

```
Undefined variable "py" or class "py.dict".

Error in conelp (line 57)
py_opt = py.dict();.
```

Comment: When you write "CVX" you mean [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/), right?  Why don't you use the *Matlab toolbox* [cvx](http://cvxr.com/cvx/)?

Comment: I am using MATLAB CVX. Can you please run the MWE I have quoted and see the answer?

Comment: Which CVX version are you using?   I don't see a `conelp` function in my version 2.1 installation.  What does `which conelp` show you?